# Maven build is picking different Jackson artefacts version on different hosts

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I have multi-module projects, which has a multiple Jackson version, though in recently added module POM and Main Project POM it's 2.9.8 (included specifically).

and One of the modules has...

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.NAME
)
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(TermQuery.class), @Type(AllMatchQuery.class)})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"queryType"})
public abstract class Query implements Serializable {
.....
}

@JsonTypeName("term")
public class TermQuery extends Query {
}
```

at the time of serialization, I am getting this response(wrong) from a few of the hosts

Case-1

```
"queryType": "term"
```

while on the rest of the hosts I am getting result as expected

Case-2

```
 "@type": "term"
```

At Case-1 expectation is annotated @type (as in case-2) while I am getting query type. Unable to pinpoint the issue, why it is happening?. though it seems Jackson version issue (I am not sure anymore now).

Other Info:-

```
 Apache Maven 3.6.3 
 [INFO] \- com.xyz:jar:1.0.5-SNAPSHOT:compile (newly added module)
```

Any thought/way out to diagnose this issue would be appreciated?

Comment: Please add your pom files; Which Maven version you are using and as much as possible of information...

Comment: #1 your problem is caused by **multi-module projects, with multiple Jackson versions**. If your main pom load the other modules, you will have this kind of errors. Try yo use just one version of jackson in all of  your projects #2 How are you packaging your app ?

Comment: @JRichardsz 1) I can't change other modules Jackson version, I do not hold ownership for them and everything was fine before my module got inducted.

Comment: #1 Is your module a jar library or a web app? #2 Are you developing an app who needs the other modules or just a module that some app is adding to its pom.xml along with the other modules which have several jackson libraries.  #3 Is the error you mention in the app or in your module?  #4 There is an option in which the final app (pom) could pick just one version of jackson

Comment: 1) jar 
2) I have developed a module and adding into the existing app which has already multiple modules having several Jackson libraries.
3) Error is in-app while installing on the boxes, (on few boxes it's fine while on the rest there is serialization error)
4) I have put Jackson library in the app pom directly as well.

Note: all the other artifacts have been excluded from the XYZ modules, only XYZ module dependency is there as per dependency:tree -Dverbose

@JRichardsz

Comment: If the main app has 3 dependencies : a,b,c and c is your module, is in this pom.xml in which jackson must be excluded from each dependency: a & b. Just c dependency should load the exact jackson version. Check this https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/739585d988d835b909a7ae6b0b4ca668 and tell me if I understood.